# Which side of Lyria train to sit on from Paris to Geneva?

Tags: trains, france, paris, switzerland, geneva

We're traveling from Paris to Geneva on the Lyria.  Is there a more scenic side to sit on? Does upper or lower level have any impact on view?
We're going first class. We'd very much like Club2 seating on the upper level with the best view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the end of the line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_du_Haut-Bugey), I would say that seating on the left side is best. You would be on the lake side in [Nantua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lac_de_Nantua) and [Sylans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TGVSE43_Sylans_12nov2010.jpg). I don't recall the first part of the journey (on the [LGV Sud-Est](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGV_Sud-Est)) as particularly scenic.

Upper level is nice on “Duplex” rolling stock but do note that many Lyria-branded trains are in fact single level. Furthermore, since seating in first class is in a 2+1 configuration, Club Duo “vis-à-vis” (face-to-face) is only available on one side of a given carriage.